Prevent some lsp from creating commands
Ocamllsp spawns new commands like OCamlSwitchNewWin, overriding some of mine.
How to prevent such ?
  local capabilities = vim.lsp.protocol.make_client_capabilities()
  capabilities = vim.tbl_deep_extend('force', capabilities, require('cmp_nvim_lsp').default_capabilities())
  
  local servers = {
    clangd = {},
    pyright = {},
    ocamllsp = {
    },
    lua_ls = {
      settings = {
        Lua = {
          completion = {
            callSnippet = 'Replace',
          },
          diagnostics = { disable = { 'missing-fields' } },
        },
      },
    },
  }

  require('mason').setup()

  local ensure_installed = vim.tbl_keys(servers or {})
  vim.list_extend(ensure_installed, {
    'stylua',
    'clang-format',
  })
  require('mason-tool-installer').setup({ ensure_installed = ensure_installed })

  require('mason-lspconfig').setup({
    handlers = {
      function(server_name)
        local server = servers[server_name] or {}
        server.capabilities = vim.tbl_deep_extend('force', {}, capabilities, server.capabilities or {})
        require('lspconfig')[server_name].setup(server)
      end,
    },
  })


Welcome to Vim :-) Could you give us an example such that we can reproduce the behavior?

Do you also have vim-ocaml installed?
